# Making text box visible/unvisible c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visible

I'm working on a windows form application and I have a button and a `textbox` in it.

When the button is pressed, it should make the `textbox` visible and hidden.

Answer (score 10):

```
myTextbox.Visible = !myTextbox.Visible;
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try Google?

```
textBox1.Visible = false;
```

You can toggle the visibility by doing:

```
if(textBox1.Visible == true)
    textBox1.Visible = false;
else
    textBox1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

WinForm:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Visible = !textBox.Visible;
}
```

WPF:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if (textBox.Visibility != System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
            textBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        else
            textBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   /* If the CTRL key is pressed when the 
      * control is clicked, hide the control. */ 
   if(Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
   {
      ((Control)sender).Hide();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox.visible=true;
```

you should try this on buttonClick event