# Hide button text behind button image

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Is there any method to hide a button text behind button image like **bring to front** or **send to back** option?

I only need to hide or show button image only as I have a code that coverts the original text `CloseButton.text = "&Close";` to `CloseButton.Text = "&Cancel";`
to perform another command so I can't use `CloseButton.Text = "";`.

Tried this link - [WinForms button with image and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611402/winforms-button-with-image-and-text) but my button size is too small that it would only show the text and not the image no matter how I mix and match `TextAlign` and `ImageAlign`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sample Button Size below:

[image: See image & text overlapping]

Comment: You tried to explain, but it's still unclear to me why you need to use the `Text` property if you don't want it displayed.

Comment: @Rotem Like I said in my post, I have a code behind that requires me to use text as I am trying to make it work that way and if there's no way around it then need to find another way.

Comment: Have your code behind use the `Tag` property rather than `Text`. Easiest way out is using properties for what they were made for.

Comment: @Rotem thanks a lot. Never tried using `Tag` before. Gonna try it out now.

Comment: @Rotem `Tags` was the right answer. I hope you could post an answer that I can mark as correct or I'll have to post one myself as I manage to make it work using your suggestion.

Comment: @Pat feel free to post and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rotem posted in the comments.

> Have your code behind use the Tag property rather than Text. Easiest way out is using properties for what they were made for.

Instead of using `CloseButton.text = "&Close";` I changed it to `CloseButton.Tag = "&Close";` and made my code worked around it to have the same function without placing an actual `Text` in my `Buttons`. Credit this asnwer to @Rotem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250082/making-text-box-visible-unvisible-c-sharp)

Place Textbox in Button and set `textbox.visible=false` method

Comment: don't use button.text property. Place new textbox in your button and use that, it's a workaround but it suits your needs

Comment: I actually tried it and it helped but the better answer was using `Tags`. Thanks anyways Frosty

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to hide a button text behind button image like
>   bring to front or send to back option?

There is no such built in but you can simply clear out the text on click event of the controls. Example: if you have radio buttons for *send to back* then on click of that clear out the control text saying `controlId.Text = string.Empty`